# Can't Find or create a new virtualenv

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, python-venv

I just got Python 3.5.2 and wanted to create a virtualenv.

I have done this before. Right now, I have a virtualenv on a Python2.7 project that I can still open with source bin/activate.

But try as I might, from /home, or from /path/to/virtualenv, or /path/to/virtualenv-$, with or without sudo and python prepended on the command line, I only get one response: no such file or directory.

This was with the -p flag so it would use 3.5.2, because 2.7.12 is still my default. If it is broken, why does the virtualenv I created for 2.7 still activate?

Then I tried pyvenv and venv (which I've never used before) from the 3.5.2 interpreter:

```
>>> pyvenv /home/malikarumi/Projects/aishah
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pyvenv' is not defined
>>> venv /home/malikarumi/Projects/aishah
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'venv' is not defined
```

and from bash:

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ malikarumi@Tetuoan2:/usr/local/bin$ python3.5    pyvenv ~/Projects/aishah
bash: malikarumi@Tetuoan2:/usr/local/bin$: No such file or directory
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~$ malikarumi@Tetuoan2:/usr/local/bin$ python3.5 venv ~/Projects/aishah
bash: malikarumi@Tetuoan2:/usr/local/bin$: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run it as a module: `python3.5 -m venv ~/Projects/aishah`. Note the `-m` option.

Comment: Alternatively, I can recommend `virtualenvwrapper` (pip installable), which makes possibly even easier: `mkvirtualenv blah --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.5` and you're all set (and `--python=/usr/local/bin/python3.5` is likely not even necessary if you installed it with Python3.5's pip).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Using virtualenv

First of all you should verify that virtualenv is really installed for Python 3.5:

`python3.5 -m pip list`

If it's not then install it either with the package manager of your distribution or by running `python3.5 -m pip install virtualenv`.

Then you can run `python3.5 -m virtualenv <newvenv>` and it should create a new virtualenv using Python 3.5 for you.

## Using venv that is already part of the standard library in Python 3.5

Simply running `python3.5 -m venv <newvenv>` should do the job.

Comment: thanks to both of you. I decided to go with the venv instead of virtualenv and this worked. the -m flag is new to me, so I've given it a look. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/

Comment: When I try that, activate and run `python --version`, I get version 2. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got more than one version of python installed, and thinking of creating a virtual environment with a specific version, say you've got python3.8 and python3.9, then you can create a virtual environment like so;

```
python3.8 -m venv <your preferred virtual environment name>
```