# mkvirtualenv not creating virtualenv when specifying python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I currently have Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed locally. I installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper with pip3. When I do not specify the the python version (i.e. $ mkvirtualenv hello) everything goes smoothly and I get the following output:

"Using base prefix '/home/rishi_gurnani/python'
New python executable in /home/rishi_gurnani/.virtualenvs/hello/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in /home/rishi_gurnani/.virtualenvs/hello/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/rishi_gurnani/.virtualenvs/hello/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/rishi_gurnani/.virtualenvs/hello/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/rishi_gurnani/.virtualenvs/hello/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/rishi_gurnani/.virtualenvs/hello/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/rishi_gurnani/.virtualenvs/hello/bin/get_env_details"

However, when I specify that I want python2.7 (i.e. $ mkvirtualenv -p python2.7 hello2) I get:

"Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/rishi_gurnani/python/bin/python2.7"

So no virtualenv is being created anywhere. In other words, I'm only able to create a virtualenv with Python 3.6. but I would also like to create one which uses 2.7 instead.

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: @mentallurg virtualenv supports the ability to create environments which use different versions of python. Why am I not able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

A question like yours has already been asked. You would want to refer to this:
[Can't Find or create a new virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814281/cant-find-or-create-a-new-virtualenv)

Make sure that your virtualenv version installed is the one suitable for Python 2.7. As far as I know pip3 is only for Python3.

Comment: Yes, when I type "python2.7 -m pip list" virtualenv is not there but it is when I type "python3.6 -m pip list". The only way I can install pip from source is with python3, when I try with python2.7 it errors out so I'm not sure how to get the correct version of pip so that the modules can be found by the command "python2.7 -m pip list"

Comment: > when I try with python2.7 it errors out. What is the error that you get? Also,try creating a  virtualenv with this command:  "virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 <project-name>" (assuming you are in some version of Linux)

Comment: my Python 3 is `python3` in my current system, so I modified `virtualenvwrapper.sh` by changing `python` to `python3` in three places. otherwise I was unable to create a virtual env. after 2020, that issue should come up less often.